# Can Visual Studio Wait Until I move off the line to show me problems?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, editor

I like (almost) immediate feedback about syntax errors and unused variables, etc.  But I find it distracting to have things highlighting and de-highlighting as I type.  Is there a way to leave the feature on but make it wait until I move off the line to check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible.

What you can do is disable the real-time semantic error highlighting, so as to get semantic errors reported only when you compile. You can also get rid entirely of error highlighting.

Both options are under `Tools > Options > Text editors > C# > Advanced`.